# How can I implement an expressions structure in java that supports evaluating and multiple types

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, expression, evaluate

In the light of writing a tool that compiles simple programs in a custom language that uses a parser for parsing simple .txt-file programs, I'm looking for an efficient way to store and evaluate expressions.
More specifically, the expression can be evaluated to a boolean, a double, and possibly other types. Double expressions can also contain mathematical functions.

I need to be able to store the expression so that I can evaluate it at the time the instruction that contains it is executed.

For example, there should be an Expression class, with children that could be DoubleExpression, or BoolExpression. A DoubleExpression can be a literal, a unary expression(square root, sine, etc) or a binary expression(comparisons, multiply,...). 
The program needs to store those instructions without losing information.

So an expression that represents a multiplication a * 2 should store that a is a global variable, and should be able to calculate its outcome every time this expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

String class has many utilities like reading word by word, StringTokenizer too. You should also check out Scanner class. IO knowledge is a must.

Comment: I already have the parsing part done, the parser calls methods that should store the info of every instruction in memory so that it can be executed at a later time. It's the data structure/hierarchy for those instructions - in particular the expressions that can be part of a statement - that boggles me.

Comment: For that you might have to do couple of parsing turns, and even go character by character parsing. I don't quite understand problem, can you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but a few years ago I wrote a rather extensive expression parser and evaluator for an extended FTP scripting language. The source code is at:

[david.tribble.com/src/java/default.html#tribble.net.ftp.shell](http://david.tribble.com/src/java/default.html#tribble.net.ftp.shell)

You will be interested in the `CommandParser.parseExpr()` method, which parses expressions and builds expression trees, and the `Interp.evalExpr()` method, which evaluates those trees.